# libgdx: Fixed-position-actor in between dependently moving actors

Tags: libgdx

Using scene2d in libgdx, I want an actor to stay fixed relative to screen, but at the same time have other actors, that is scaling and moving dependently of each other, above it (covering) and below it, as shown here:

[image]

The only way I have found the fixed actor (red) to have a z-level in between the others, is to make it a child of the blue actor in the figure (as green is), but then it is scaling and moving together with its parent (blue).

I tried to solve that by overriding draw() in the fixed actor like this:

```
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha){
        Vector2 coord = new Vector2(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y);
        getStage().screenToStageCoordinates(coord);
        stageToLocalCoordinates(coord);
        setPosition(coord.x, coord.y);
        setScale(1/getParent().getScaleX());
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }
```

...but the result is that it is drawn at two places (every other time) creating a flickering effect.

Are there better ways to achieve this effect?

If overriding draw() is the way to go, where do I go wrong in the implementation?

Comment: If you add an actor to a group it is scaled with the group and the scaling of the actor is relativ to the scaling of the group, as much as i know. I did not really understand what you want to achieve. Can you explain it agian please? Try to make an example or tell me what the objects stand for in real life (for example the green one is a person the red one is a weapon or what ever)

Comment: Blue is the group. Green is added to it and scaling and moving with it. That is all good and what I want. Then I want another actor to be displayed in between, so that it is covering blue and can itself be covered by green, but at the same time stay fixed relative to the screen.

Comment: So the SIZE of the red thing should be always the same? Or also position? And do you resize the group?

Comment: Size and position of red fixed. Group is moving and scaling. Found a solution though: substitute 4th line in the code above with: getParent().stageToLocalCoordinates(coord). But not sure if overriding draw() is the best way.

Comment: So you add red to the group, only that it can be in the middle of the 2?

Comment: That's correct. So ideally it should not be part of the group, but as mentioned in the question, that's the only way I have found that sets its z-level so that it is in between the group's z-level values.

Comment: Okay so i am sorry than i can't help. It could be that there is no other way. But adding an actor to a group to which it does not belong sounds bad... I hope you find another solution!

Answer (score 1):

Calling parent's stageToLocalCoordinates() rather than its own works:

```
   public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha){
        Vector2 coord = new Vector2(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y);
        getStage().screenToStageCoordinates(coord);
        getParent().stageToLocalCoordinates(coord);
        setPosition(coord.x, coord.y);
        setScale(1/getParent().getScaleX());
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }
```

Not sure if it the most efficient solution though...